# Is SQL Server Express 14 appropriate to use for conducting calculations over tables?

Tags: sql, gpgpu

I am building a factory QC fixture that measures, analyzes, and stores data on the physical dimensions of products leaving a factory. The raw data for each measured product starts off as a table with 5 columns, and up to 86000 rows. To get useful information, this table must undergo some processing. This data is collected in LabVIEW, but stored in an SQL server database. **I want to ask whether it's best to pass the data to the server and process it in there (via stored procedure), or process it outside the server and then add it in?**

Let me tell you about the processing to be done:

To get meaningful information from the raw data, each record in the table needs to be passed into a function that calculates parameters of interest. The function also uses other records (I'll call them secondary records) from the raw table.  **The contents of the record originally passed into the function dictate what secondary records the function uses to perform calculations. The function also utilizes some trigonometric operators.** My concern is that SQL will be very slow or buggy when doing calculations over a big table. I am not sure if this sort of task is something SQL is efficient at doing, or if I'm better off trying to get it done through the GPU using CUDA.

Hopefully I'm clear enough on what I need, please let me know if not.

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: If you're thinking that there is a chance that any CPU will be too slow and CUDA is the alternative, then I think you've already answered your own question.

As for SQL Server Express 2014, It only allows the lesser of 1 socket or 4 cores for processing data.  C# allows you to parallel process beyond this, and CUDA on GPU allows even further perallelism.

Calculations within SQL Server are only as buggy as the code you write, btw.

Comment: I appreciate your response @EastOfJupiter. I too felt like I answered myself toward the end of the question. My problem is that I'm a mechanical engineer that just got handy with Access/SQL a few months ago. Now it looks like I have a whole new can of worms to sort through with CUDA. I was really hoping someone would say "Yeah, SQL will work just fine." but it looks like I'm going with my gut on this one.

Comment: When I'm developing DB solutions (tables, stored procs, etc) I like to make sure that I do as few computations in the DB as possible.  I always tell the developers who consume my solutions that my database stores data, it does not invent information.

But, SQL does do a decent job at aggretages, and other higher math functions.  I code a ton of computations in my reporting services stored procedures that process millions of rows.  These solutions DO invent information, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally we need SQL server to help us sort, search, index, update data and *share* the data with multiple users (according to their privileges) at the same time. I see no work for SQL server in the task you've described. Looks like no one needs any of those 860000 raws before they've been processed.

Comment: Thanks @Serg for your reply.  I was hoping the calculations were simple enough to pin onto the server, but after describing it in writing, I see that's not the case.  I'll use SQL to organize/manage the data like you talked about, and leave the data manipulation to something else.  Thanks again.

Comment: @George, you are welcome. Trying to properly put a question is half an answer. Or may be even more in this case.